# Python/Pygame Creating a start screen with classes/functions

Tags: python, pygame, startup

I'm currently trying to create a screen at the beginning of my game that when I hit any key, it will active my game loop. I've gotten about 80% to getting the screen to work I just can't get the last of it. I'm just trying to get where once I pass the starting screen, the first level will activate. Any help/input is greatly appreciated. Thank you. The main areas of concern are surrounded by 3 asterisks in the `Player` class. The method `wait` and `level`

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
SCR_WID, SCR_HEI = 640, 480
LEVEL = 1
hit = pygame.mixer.Sound('pickup.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.load('play.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
musicPlaying = True

class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.p3, self.p4 = SCR_WID/2, 16
        self.p5, self.p6 = SCR_WID/2, 464
        self.speed = 3
        self.padWid, self.padHei = 8, 128
        self.padWid3, self.padHei4 = 128, 8
        self.score = 0
        self.scoreFont = pygame.font.Font("imagine_font.ttf", 64)

    def music(self):
        global hit
        hit = pygame.mixer.Sound('pickup.wav')
        pygame.mixer.music.load('play.wav')
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
        global musicPlaying
        musicPlaying = True

    def scoring(self):
            scoreBlit = self.scoreFont.render(str(self.score), 1, (0,0,0))
            screen.blit(scoreBlit, (32, 16))
            if self.score == 15:
                print ("player 1 wins!")
                exit()

    def scoring1(self):
            scoreBlit = self.scoreFont.render(str(self.score), 1, (0,0,0))
            screen.blit(scoreBlit, (SCR_HEI+92, 16))
            if self.score == 15:
                print ("Player 2 wins!")
                exit()

    ***def wait(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    player.level(player, enemy, ball)
                    return
    def level(self, player, enemy, ball):
        while LEVEL < 4:
            font = pygame.font.SysFont("Drawing with markers", 48)
            text = font.render("Pong", 1, (255, 100, 100))
            text1 = font.render("Press a key to start", 1, (255, 100, 100))
            screen.blit(text, (250,190))
            screen.blit(text1, (133,270))
            pygame.display.flip()
            player.wait()
            if LEVEL == 1:
                self.x, self.y = 16, SCR_HEI/2
                self.x1, self.y1 = SCR_WID-16, SCR_HEI/2***

    def movement(self):
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_w]:
                self.y -= self.speed
            elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
                self.y += self.speed

            if self.y <= 0:
                self.y = 0
            elif self.y >= SCR_HEI-128:
                self.y = SCR_HEI-128

            keys1 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys1[pygame.K_UP]:
                self.y1 -= self.speed
            elif keys1[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                self.y1 += self.speed

            if self.y1 <= 0:
                self.y1 = 0
            elif self.y >= SCR_HEI-128:
                self.y1 = SCR_HEI-128

            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                self.p3 -= self.speed
            elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
                self.p3 += self.speed

            if self.p3 <= 0:
                self.p3 = 0
            elif self.p3 >= SCR_WID-128:
                self.p3 = SCR_WID-128

            keys1 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys1[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                self.p5 -= self.speed
            elif keys1[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                self.p5 += self.speed

            if self.p5 <= 0:
                self.p5 = 0
            elif self.p5 >= SCR_WID-128:
                self.p5 = SCR_WID-128

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (self.x, self.y, self.padWid, self.padHei))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (self.x1, self.y1, self.padWid, self.padHei))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (self.p3, self.p4, self.padWid3, self.padHei4))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (self.p5, self.p6, self.padWid3, self.padHei4))

class Ball():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x, self.y = SCR_WID/2, SCR_HEI/2
        self.x1, self.y1 = SCR_WID/2, SCR_HEI/2
        self.p3, self.p4 = SCR_WID/2, SCR_HEI/2
        self.p5, self.p6 = SCR_WID/2, SCR_HEI/2
        self.speed_x = -2
        self.speed_y = 2
        self.size = 12

    def movement(self, player, enemy):
        self.x += self.speed_x
        self.y += self.speed_y

        if self.y <= 0:
            self.speed_y *= -1
        elif self.y >= SCR_HEI-self.size:
            self.speed_y *= -1

        if self.x <= 0:
            self.__init__()
            enemy.score += 1
            if musicPlaying:
                hit.play()
        elif self.x >= SCR_WID-self.size:
            self.__init__()
            self.speed_x = 3
            player.score += 1
            if musicPlaying:
                hit.play()
        for n in range(-self.size, player.padHei):
            if self.y == player.y + n:
                    if self.x <= player.x + player.padWid:
                        self.speed_x *= -1
                        break
            n += 1
        self.x1 += self.speed_x
        self.y1 += self.speed_y

        if self.y1 <= 0:
            self.speed_y *= -1
        elif self.y1 >= SCR_HEI-self.size:
            self.speed_y *= -1

        if self.x1 <= 0:
            self.__init__()
            enemy.score += 1
            if musicPlaying:
                hit.play()
        elif self.x1 >= SCR_WID-self.size:
            self.__init__()
            self.speed_x = 3
            player.score += 1
            if musicPlaying:
                hit.play()
        for n in range(-self.size, enemy.padHei):
            if self.y1 == enemy.y1 + n:
                    if self.x1 >= enemy.x1 - enemy.padWid:
                        self.speed_x *= -1
                        break
            n += 1
        self.p3 += self.speed_x
        self.p4 += self.speed_y

        if self.p4 <= 0:
            self.speed_x *= -1
        elif self.p4 >= SCR_HEI-self.size:
            self.speed_x *= -1

        if self.p3 <= 0:
            self.__init__()
            enemy.score += 1
        elif self.p3 >= SCR_WID-self.size:
            self.__init__()
            self.speed_y = 3
            player.score += 1
        for n in range(-self.size, enemy.padHei4):
            if self.p4 == enemy.p4 + n:
                    if self.p3 >= enemy.p3 - enemy.padWid3:
                        self.speed_y *= -1
                        break
            n += 1
        self.p5 += self.speed_x
        self.p6 += self.speed_y

        if self.p6 <= 0:
            self.speed_x *= -1
        elif self.p6 >= SCR_HEI-self.size:
            self.speed_x *= -1

        if self.p5 <= 0:
            self.__init__()
            enemy.score += 1
        elif self.p5 >= SCR_WID-self.size:
            self.__init__()
            self.speed_y = 3
            player.score += 1
        for n in range(-self.size, enemy.padHei4):
            if self.p6 == enemy.p6 + n:
                    if self.p5 >= enemy.p5 - enemy.padWid3:
                        self.speed_y *= -1
                        break
            n += 1

    def draw(self):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (112,138,144), (self.x, self.y, 12, 12))

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCR_WID, SCR_HEI))
player = Player() 
ball = Ball()
enemy = Player()
##level = level(score)

def main():
##    player.music()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                print ("Game exited by user")
                sys.exit()
        else:
            False
            pygame.font.init()
            backgroundimage = pygame.image.load("background.png")
            pygame.display.set_caption("Justin's pong")
            player.level(player, enemy, ball)
            ball.movement(player, enemy)
            player.movement()
            enemy.movement()
            position = (0,0)
            screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            screen.blit(backgroundimage, position)
            ball.draw()
            player.draw()
            player.scoring()
            enemy.draw()
            enemy.scoring1()
            pygame.display.flip()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 60
    clock.tick(FPS)
    player.music()


main()
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to write a function:

```
def intro():
    smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)
    while intro == True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                intro = False
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        text = smallfont.render("press any key to continue",True , (0, 0, 0))
        gameDisplay.blit(text, [320,240])
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
intro()
main()
```

Comment: Okay so I have that, but how do I get it so it will loop into my level method so that when I hit "any key" it'll start with level 1?

Comment: you have to add "intro()" in every point before the beginning of the new level: i think they are in the function "level" so right under the while loop "LEVEL<4"

Comment: I must be doing something wrong still. The loop works. The message is displayed and everything. The only problem is that the code is still not executing when I hit any key. Any ideas?

Comment: try to write "if event.key == pygame.K_a: intro = False" under the "elif: event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:" then start the game and press "a" when asked to press a key. if this work do  that for every key

Comment: What that is doing is making the game code only run when you hit the letter a.